# Nashorn Parser API on JDK 8

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

Looking for a Java/JDK API for parsing JavaScript (including Nashorn Extensions) I stumbled upon [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sundararajana/d295df5965134e2c30be), which according to an inline comment requires JDK 9 to run. Is there a reliable way to accomplish the same on current or planned releases of JDK 8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nashorn Parser API ( http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/236 ) is jdk9 specific API. On jdk8 or jdk8 update, there is support for script parser function.

load("nashorn:parser.js");

and call "parse" function from script. This function returns a JSON object that represents AST of the script parsed.

See this sample: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/nashorn/file/bfea11f8c8f2/samples/astviewer.js

Comment: Thanks! How awesome to get a reply from an inside man :) (Which you seem to be, right?)

Answer (score -1):

While you can definitely use the parser via Nashorn's JavaScript, it's even nicer in Java to use it through the JAVA API

```
    import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptUtils;
    import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context;
    import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException;
    import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ErrorManager;
    import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.options.Options;

    // set up the environment
    Options options = new Options("nashorn");
    options.set("anon.functions", true);
    options.set("parse.only", true);
    options.set("scripting", true);

    ErrorManager errors = new ErrorManager();
    Context contextm = new Context(options, errors, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    Context.setGlobal(contextm.createGlobal());


    // then for each bit of parsing
    String parseTree = ScriptUtils.parse(some_code_string, "nashorn", false);
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. jdk.nashorn.internal.* are internal implementation packages of nashorn. This will fail to run with security manager enabled (if your class is untrusted). With jdk9, these are not even exported from nashorn module and so it'll fail to compile even.

Comment: Fair point. There's another side effect of this, which I discovered. If you do the above you cannot also use Nashorn via `ScriptEngine`. In the end, I created a small `js` to use the parser within Nashorn itself.